# Error 1004 when calling subroutine twice (or more) consecutively in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been struggling with this error for about an hour and a half and haven't been able to find an answer.  Perhaps you could help me out.

I have a short sub that locates a column labeled "Filter" in a sheet.  It turns on an autofilter for that column and hides it.

```
Sub Test1()

    Call FilterHide(Worksheets("Integration"))
    Call FilterHide(Worksheets("Integration Matrix"))

End Sub

Sub FilterHide(ByVal target As Worksheet)
'
'Searches for filter column, then autofilters selection to show only "Show"

    Dim clm As Integer

    If IsError(Application.Match("Filter", target.Range("1:1"), 0)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    clm = Application.Match("Filter", target.Range("1:1"), 0)
    target.Range(Columns(clm), Columns(clm)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Show"
    target.Range(Columns(clm), Columns(clm)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

'FilterHide()' works fine when I call it once. However, when I attempt to call it twice from another sub with different sheets, it breaks (e.g. 'Test1()' above).  I get "run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worsksheet' failed."  The debugger then points me to the following line

```
target.Range(Columns(clm), Columns(clm)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Show"
```

I can run `FilterHide()` successfully for all sheets if I do it one at a time.  It's only when I call it multiple times that I get errors.  My ultimate goal is to create a `Worksheet_Deactivate()` event that runs `FilterHide()` for about 7 different worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target.Range(Columns(clm), Columns(clm)).AutoFilter
```

Here the unqualified `Columns(clm)` will refer to the ActiveSheet, not `target`.

You need:

```
target.Range(target.Columns(clm), target.Columns(clm)).AutoFilter
```

but this reduces to

```
target.Columns(clm).AutoFilter
```

Comment: That solved it. Thanks for the quick response, Tim.